# Reconnecting reports faster

Tags: sql-server, excel

Just recently, I had moved all stored procedures from one database in SQL Server to another, because of a database update. I have many excel reports that are connected to these stored procedures, and I was wondering if there was a fast way to reconnect every report to the new database, instead of doing each one manually.

Comment: how are they connected might be a starting point?

Comment: Maybe you can create a [`synonym`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177544(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Apologies, I created this question quickly and missed out details! All connections are SQL server connections.

Comment: Can you loop collection of connections? Not sure how you are connected so maybe look at the many examples already on SO e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114223/modify-an-embedded-connection-string-in-microsoft-excel-macro?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa