# Save the changes of data source for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, connection

Hello this is my script for changing the data source and catalog.

When I run the script I can see in the console that the source table and catalog are changing, but when I enter in my DataModel in Excel and check Existing Connection I still see the old one.

Also, when I open the folder and check date modified I see that it's saved the excel file, but the changes for Data Source and Catalog are not there.

```
Sub changeConn()
Dim conn As Variant
Dim connectString As String

  For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
  
    connectString = ActiveWorkbook.Connections("NGNSQLMDR MDR Sales").OLEDBConnection.Connection
    Debug.Print "Before changes: "; connectString
    connectString = Replace(connectString, "Catalog=MDR", "Catalog=MDR")
    connectString = Replace(connectString, "Data Source=SQLMDR", "Data Source=sql.Company.local")
    Debug.Print "After Changes: "; connectString

    conn.OLEDBConnection.Connection = connectString

  Next conn

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code is just creating a `String` which contains your changes. You don't actually USE that new string to do anything! After your replacement lines, you need to use something like `conn.ConnectionString = connectString` in order to change the actual connection object's connection string to your `connectString` with the new details.

Comment: I added before Next conn and I receive error: application defined or object defined error

This is the line of code that I added:
conn.OLEDBConnection.Connection = connectString

Comment: Do you know which object the `conn` is after the `For Each conn` line? I don't know if you're using OLE or ADODB con objects or what

Comment: Hi, I'm using OLEDB. I don't really know how to handle this process, I'm reading and trying to figure out how I can save changes.

Comment: Can you check what the exact object is in the `conn` variant when the code is running using the `VIEW` > `LOCALS WINDOW` - it should be very simple to set a connection string on the `conn` object but there are different types of connection object so in order to give you an accurate answer it'd be best to know what the `conn` object is.

Comment: e.g. for an `ADODB.Connection` it's literally just `Conn.ConnectionString = MyConnectionString` but I'm not sure about others.

Comment: Hi thanks for that you are trying to help me and give me advice what to do!
I put it as a comment the screenshot of this window.

Comment: I found an answer that was using the same conn `OLEDB` objects and it said to put "OLEDB" before the connection string, please see my full answer below

Answer (score 0):

So after the discussion in the comments which showed that your string was changing but not being assigned to the connection `conn` object, you were then very close when you tried / added to the question `conn.OLEDBConnection.Connection = connectString`

but according to this thread here...

[Modify an embedded Connection String in microsoft excel macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114223/modify-an-embedded-connection-string-in-microsoft-excel-macro)

...you need to set your connection string to have "OLEDB;" at the start, so prepending your current connection string, so maybe try this:

```
conn.OLEDBConnection.Connection = "OLEDB;" & connectString
```

The answer in that thread has quite a few upvotes so I'm hoping this works the same for you!

Comment: Also it's not working in this way :( It's creating double OLEDB

Comment: Here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/KvCqBgL
It's very strange, because it's not accepting any solutions...

Comment: Hmm so your con string already has the OLEDB at the start of it... I don't know why it's not allowing you to set the new string