# How can I change the command text of an SQL connected table in Excel using VBA?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, vb.net

Our company has a lot of macros in VBA. We are trying to replace some of it with RPA etc, but there are alot and some development on them is therefore required.

In certain cases we have macros that use tables, which have SQL connections. Recently it's become relevant in alot of them to use variable conditions in the SQL query itself.

I know I can make SQL queries directly from VBA, but for alot of these we're not building the macro from scratch, we're modifying a large system of existing macros.

When an Excel table has an SQL connection, I can go to the connection properties and change both connection string, and command text, through the Excel UI. My question is, how can I change this using VBA?

To give an example, I might have a table in excel, and going to Table Design, and connection properties and definition I can see a connection-string and a query. Let's say the query is like:

```
SELECT thing FROM mytable WHERE CustomerNumber = Hardcoded
```

I need to be able to let a user enter a customer number that is different from the hardcoded one, and then for VBA to go change the connection properties of the Excel table.

What I have tried so far, amounts to googling unsuccesfully what the correct syntax for something like this is. Which is why I now ask.

EDIT: Clarification

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also check SO, there are several examples of how to connect to SQL using VBA

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I've read the guidelines, and honestly posted my question believing it to fall within them. The question I ask is specific: "How to change the connection property of an Excel table with an SQL connection". I already know all about making SQL queries from inside VBA, and I explained why that isn't what I need. Finally, I have already attempted googling and reading microsoft documentations etc, and specified within my question that I wasn't able to find an answer on my own. If you think my question is bad, will you specify the issue? I will amend my post if necessary.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns It struck me; my post probably looks like code-begging. I am so sorry. The reason I haven't written any code is because I genuinly cannot find any syntax that does something I assume is built into VBA. I don't expect, want or need anyone to write my code for me. An ideal answer for me "The method you want is [a method]. It can change connection properties" or even just a confirmation that this isn't something VBA can do on it's own would be a fully accepted answer as well.

Comment: This post looks as though it might help ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114223/modify-an-embedded-connection-string-in-microsoft-excel-macro

Comment: Just checking, you've tagged this as both vb.net and vba.  While some syntax similarities, it can't be both.  What sort of solution are you actually looking for?

Comment: @user10186832 That was exactly what I am looking for. I think this question can be closed.

Comment: Thanks @Jens-Emil - upvote my hat?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384712/show-off-your-hats-2022-edition?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top